# Random NullPointerException with LibGDX

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, libgdx

So here's the thing. In my firebase panel, I got reports about the following NullPointerException in my Android app:

```
     Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'float com.badlogic.gdx.Graphics.getDeltaTime()' on a null object reference
blue.rtrngames.papersorcery.PaperSorcery.render (PaperSorcery.java:86)
```

The line in question is simply the first line of my render method, which looks like this:

```
@Override
public void render()
{
    tick(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()); // <- this is the line
```

So Gdx.graphics is null there. This only happens for about 1% of the users, right after start-up, and even then seems to be completely rare and not happening every time. I cannot reproduce this crash; it simply doesn't happen for me.

What should I do about this? I can't imagine that just implementing a null-check would help here, since there has to be something gone wrong if Gdx.graphics is null? I imagine the game would just render a blackscreen or sth. like that the whole time?

Comment: have you tried implementing a null-check and see if it's worked?

Comment: When you see null statics like this, the problem is generally a race condition between initializing the library and using it somewhere.  I'd put in some checks for that, and try to ensure initialization finishes first, or that render checks that its initialized before using it.

Comment: @Aaron I would, but the problem is that I cannot see the result the user would get. If the game then just continues on to render a black screen or sth. like that, I would much rather have them get a crash and restart the game so it will work.

Comment: Ah, sadly I do not know enough about Android development to help, sorry :/

Comment: Can you show your AndroidLauncher class? Are you doing anything with Threads directly?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Gdx Context is initialized

In other words, don't call any `Gdx.(...)` methods until after your `create()` method starts execution